# Triangle waveform in OrCAD

Tags: operational-amplifier, orcad

I faced with problem in my project. I have to build circuit in OrCAD that should to generate triangle signal. I tried to use IC 555, but get sawtooth signal. After that i used hours and tens of circuits to figure out triangle signal in OrCAD, but it didn't help.
I found a lot of circuits and it works in LTSpice or in real circuits, but not in OrCAD.
I have 5V supply and 10-15 kHz frequency.
If somebody has this circuit, i will be very gratefull

this circuit that i found in internet 
[image]

this is mine, how i see it( i'm newbee in OrCAD)
[enter image description here][2]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: If you have circuits working in LTSpice, why don't you just redraw one in OrCAD?

Comment: Post your LTSpice circuit which works and tell us what error you get when you try to implement the same circuit in OrCAD

Comment: added circuits.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a triangle wave generator but it's all wrong- U1B should be an op-amp not a comparator- it's an integrator. Having V11 in there means that U1B cannot respond to U1A's output, it will just go 'open' (it's open collector).

It might conceivably work if  you add a 3K pullup to +5 on the output of U1B, remove V11, and add a 10uF capacitor from the output to the negative rail (the latter is necessary because the comparator won't want to play nicely when you try to make it act like an op-amp- it is LM339/393-specific - don't try this with another random type of comparator).

Better to try replacing the LM339 with a rail-to-rail CMOS op-amp. Be sure to follow the tutorials carefully to add the device if you can't find one in your PSPICE library, it's somewhat non-trivial.